# What stylesheet gets used by loading ajax content?

Tags: css, ajax, stylesheet

I am trying to find out whether a piece of content included via ajax, needs it's own call to the stylesheet, or relies upon the stylesheet loaded of the calling page...

It just isn't clear how it is being styled, and what is the source of that stylings....

My educated gut tells me it get it's styling from the calling page, but i'd like to see some solid reliable proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dynamic content will be styled by whatever rules are already present.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you can see detailed information about the styling of the page as the AJAX is being executed.

Comment: I have, and how does it explain what style the newly ajaxed content is using?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it opens a new window or tab in a browser, it's part of the page, and uses the same stylesheets.